# Is it okay to use a static Simple Injector DI container in my Azure Function?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, simple-injector

I have a Simple Injector DI Container which helps instantiate the various dependencies I'll need for my function. I know static variables have special treatment in Azure Functions and I want to make sure I'm doing it right. Here's my code below. Is this correct?

```
public static class DeviceDataFunction
{
    public static Container Container = SimpleInjectionInitializer.Initialize();

    [FunctionName("DeviceDataFunction")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("devicedatatopic", "devicedatasubscription", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = @"ConnectionStringKey")]string data, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger log)
    {
        var logger = new ILoggerAdapter(log);

        logger.Info($"DeviceDataFunction ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {data}");

        try
        {
            var DeviceDataService = new DeviceDataHelper(logger,
                Container.GetInstance<IDeviceDataProvider>(),
                Container.GetInstance<IDeviceProvider>(),
                Container.GetInstance<IDeviceAlarmProvider>(),
                Container.GetInstance<IAlarmTopicHandler>(),
                Container.GetInstance<ICacheClient>());
            DeviceDataService.Process(data);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var message = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message : ex.Message;
            message += (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.StackTrace + "\n" + ex.InnerException.StackTrace : ex.StackTrace;
            logger.Error(message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise your current approach, but to prevent repeating myself, please read [this](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/536).

Answer (score 0):

It looks technically correct.

Azure Functions don't have any special treatment for statics, it's just that because a Function is always static, you have to use static initializers.